# To assign values to a Dictionary

Tags: c#, .net, readonly, accessor

I am getting below mentioned error when assgining JSON object like this:

```
 pushNotification.NotificationMessageList = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, string>>(response);
```

Here NotificationMessageList is a Dictionary  as mentioned below:

```
Dictionary<string, string> NotificationMessageList { get; }
```

> Error: Property or indexer 'IPushNotifications.NotificationMessageList' cannot be assigned to -- it is read only (CS0200)

Can anyone assist me to fix the issue?

Comment: The only way is to loop through the temp dict and add each one to your readonly dict.

Comment: Error message says it all. You cannot assign or set the value of `NotificationMessageList`

Answer (score 4):

You have defined the `Dictionary` as `read-only property`, So it won't allow you to assign values if you really want to assign means to make it as normal property, include set; which means the property definition will be like this:

```
Dictionary<string, string> NotificationMessageList { get; set;}
```

The getter and setter are known as Accessors, you can read more about them from [This MSDN Blog](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa287786(v=vs.71).aspx)

Comment: not related to this answer but to your profile, you wrote a wrong word there, *Profectional Profile* should be *Professional Profile* - really when I saw *Profectional* I just thought of something related to *Confectionery*.

Comment: @Hopeless : Thank you for the valuable suggestion. I have updated

Answer (score 0):

obviously you can't deserialise response into a dictionary. would you consider using JObject instead? it's easy to use and quite close to dictionary.

```
var o = JObject.Parse(response);
//to get the value
var value = o["key_name"].Value<type>()
```